# Updating a label with an integer from external source

Tags: swift, xcode

I am currently trying to build a label using the help of `Snapkit`.

This label should replicate the data given to it from an external source in the UI.

This is the code I currently have.

I would like to incorporate an `IBOutlet` and change the `Int` that is represented in the circle.

I am trying to create this in my own custom class. Please see my code thus far below.

Thanks

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class NumberInCircleView: UIView {

    var numberLabel: UILabel!




    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.setupViews()
    }



    func setupViews() {



        self.numberLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        self.addSubview(self.numberLabel)
        self.numberLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 30
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.numberLabel.text = "1"
        self.numberLabel.textAlignment = .center
        self.numberLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        self.numberLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.numberLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5        
    }

}
```

Comment: You could set the label text like 
self.numberLabel.text = "\(the integer value)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the integer by making it string.

```
var count:Int = 0
self.numberLabel.text = "\(count)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a count variable:

```
var count = 0
```

If you need to change the value displayed in your numberLabel (which should be declared as `@IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!` at the top of your class if it's an `IBOutlet`) using this count variable, then you would simply go for:

```
let customView = NumberInCircleView()
customView.numberLabel.text = "\(count)"
```

or:

```
customView.numberLabel.text = String(describing: count)
```

Whenever you need to update your label's text using the count.